# MLE of Urn Without Replacement Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, hypergeometric-function

An urn has W white balls where W is unknown. Suppose that R=5 Red balls are added to the urn and then a random sample of N=10 balls is selected. But this time, Suppose that we continue to draw balls one at a time without replacement until the last Red ball is selected. Let R=5 be the number of Red alls added and suppose that the last (5=Rth) ball is drawn on the K=13th draw. Find the MLE for W.

Attempt: Without replacement means its a hypergeometric problem. I'm supposed to use excel to solve this problem and I know excel has a built in HYPGEOM.DIST() function where we plug in 5 variables: K which is for Prob(X=K), N which is the number of balls, T which is teh total # of balls in the urn, S which is the number of "success" balls and a zero which is a flag. My issue is that I input this : HYPGEOM.DIST(13,10,5,10-A) where A represents the number of balls drawn which increases by each trial. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I see the probability calculation as:

$$P(\mbox{$5^{th}$ red ball occurs on $13^{th}$ ball}) = P(\mbox{$4$ red balls in sample of $12$}) \times P(13^{th} \mbox{ ball is red})$$

because the first $4$ red balls can occur anywhere in the first $12$ balls drawn but the last red ball must be the $13^{th}$ ball drawn.

Now, $P(\mbox{$4$ red balls in sample of $12$})$ does have hypergeometric distribution and in Excel, defining "success" as a white ball, we want the $5$ parameters to be:

\begin{eqnarray*}
1: && \mbox{Number of "successes" in sample} &=& 12-4 = 8 \\
2: && \mbox{Size of sample} &=& 12 \\
3: && \mbox{Number of "successes" in population} &=& A1 \\
4: && \mbox{Size of population} &=& A1 + 5 \\
5: && \mbox{Cumulative} &=& \mbox{False}
\end{eqnarray*}

Column $A$ is assumed to have the number of white balls in the population, taking values $8,9,\ldots$. It's obviously impossible for there to be fewer than $8$ white balls.

For the second factor on the RHS of the above equation, after $12$ balls are drawn, $4$ of which are red, we have $1$ red ball and $A1 - 8$ white balls left in the urn. Therefore:

$$P(13^{th} \mbox{ ball is red}) = \dfrac{1}{A1 - 7}$$

Therefore, the Excel formula needed is:

$$HYPGEOM.DIST(8,12,A1,A1+5,FALSE)/(A1-7)$$

This gave me output:

\begin{eqnarray*}
A && B \\
8 && 0.384615385 \\
9 && 0.247252747 \\
10 && 0.164835165 \\
11 && 0.113324176 \\
12 && 0.079993536 \\
13 && 0.057773109 \\
14 && 0.042569659 \\
15 && 0.031927245 \\
16 && 0.02432552 \\
17 && 0.018796992 \\
18 && 0.01471069 \\
19 && 0.011645963 \\
20 && 0.00931677
\end{eqnarray*}